# SWIFT - MACOS - Managing keypress event with 2 viewcontrollers

Tags: swift, macos, viewcontroller, keypress, keyevent

i hope you can help me:

I´m developing a macOS app in Swift. It has 2 viewcontrollers, the main controller ("HomeView") and the second one ("ListaViewController")

I´m using:

```
somecounter = 5
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
if event.keyCode == 124  {
      somecounter += 1 //Right arrow
}
if event.keyCode == 123  {
      somecounter -= 1 //Left arrow
}
}
```

At first it works, if i press right arrow the result is counter = 6 and if i press left arrow, counter = 4

Then i used a button to open the second viewcontroller like this:

```
if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ListaView") as? ListaViewController {
            ventana = "Lista"
            self.view.window?.contentViewController = controller
         }
```

and then back to the main controller like this:

```
if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "HomeView") as? ViewController {
            
            self.view.window?.contentViewController = controller
        }
```

The problem is, that when i go back to the main controller and press right arrow, if somecounter was 5, when i press right arrow it becames 7, and becames 3 if i press left arrow. It executes the code on keypress event TWICE if i opened second controller (i checked it was happening writing `print("Test")`, and it was printed twice)

So how can i solve it??

Any help would we great

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which class is `keyDown` implemented and when is `somecounter = 5` executed?

Comment: KeyDown is implemented is main controller class--> class ViewController: NSViewController { here} 

And Somecounter = 5 is on main viewcontroller viewDidLoad() function

Comment: Really dont know how to solve it...

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Using the code i posted, i run my app and test the keypress function.

Counter = 5

i pressed "right arrow" and then counter became 6

I click a button to load ListaViewController, press another button to get back to the first controller, press "right arrow" and counter became 8 (it was 6).

i see in the debug window, that it becames 7 and then became 8. So the keypress function is fired twice (if i load another viewcontroller), if i stay in the first view controller, the function works ok